# Laravel include relationship result if one exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I am trying to write a query where all items are returned (products) and if a relationship exists for that particular item (many to many) then that information is included too. When I include the relationship at the moment on the query it only returns items that have that relationship rather thatn every single item, regardless of whether that relationship exists or not.

Here is my query at the moment:

```
public static function filterProduct($vars) {

        $query = Product::query();

        if((array_key_exists('order_by', $vars)) && (array_key_exists('order', $vars))) {
            $query = $query->orderBy($vars['order_by'], $vars['order']);
        }

        if(array_key_exists('category_id', $vars) && $vars['category_id'] != 0) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($vars) {
                return $q->where('id', $vars['category_id']);
            });
        }

        if(array_key_exists('manufacturer_id', $vars)) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('manufacturer', function($q) use ($vars) {
                return $q->where('id', $vars['manufacturer_id']);
            });
        }

        $query = $query->whereHas('options', function($q) use ($vars) {

        });
```

As you can see, when an item has the 'options' relationship I need to have that particular row include details of that relationship in the returned date. With the code as it is though it is only returning items that have this relationship rather than every single item.

Can someone advise me as to how this is achieved please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid as it was so simple but it was solved by adding this:

$query = $query->with('options');